# Interesting stdext::hash_value() implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hash, c++11

I was trying some hashing algorithms with `stdext::hash_value()` on VS2010 and realized this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xhash>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    std::cout << "x64" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "x32" << std::endl;
#endif

    std::cout << stdext::hash_value(345.34533) << std::endl;
    std::cout << stdext::hash_value(345.566) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

// Output is:
// x64
//3735928758
//3735928758
```

I tried some other couples of double variable that has the same integer but different fractional part. Like 1.234 vs 1.568. Hash values were always the same. So I took a look at source of `hash_value()` and saw

```
#define _HASH_SEED  (size_t)0xdeadbeef

template<class _Kty> inline
size_t hash_value(const _Kty& _Keyval)
{   // hash _Keyval to size_t value one-to-one
    return ((size_t)_Keyval ^ _HASH_SEED);
}
```

`_KeyVal` is cast to `size_t` which does not make sense to me. The function simply ignores the fractional part of double. What is the logic behind this implementation? Is it a bug or feature?

Comment: I think this function actually originates from Visual Studio 6. This could explain a lot.

Comment: @dauphic: I don't know about Visual Studio 6 but it is in `stdext` namespace in `<xhash>` header. Are those old?

Comment: Yes, the contents of `stdext` were originally located in the `std` namespace, but they were moved to `stdext` since they aren't part of the standard library (and therefore shouldn't be in the `std` namespace). I'm not sure which version moved them, but they're in `stdext` on Visual Studio 7, so they have to date back to Visual Studio 6, which was released 1998, or earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdext::hash_value isn't a hash function.  It's the input to a hash function, you specialize it for your type so that it can be used as a key for the stdext hash classes.  There doesn't seem to be any documentation for it however.  The actual hash function is stdext::hash_compare.

But because there is no default specialization of hash_value it uses the convert-to-int method which ignores the fractional part.

There is an almost-identical bug for the standard std::tr1::hash/std::hash function up until vc10:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361851/std-tr1-hash-float-or-hash-double-is-poorly-implemented

in vc10 std::hash gets a double specialization that hashes the bits.  I guess stdext is considered obsolete now so there's no fix for it even in vc10.

Comment: The link specified in above answer is dead. Can you update it?

Answer (score 1):

The function is written to work with any type of data.  It makes no assumption about the size and hence is inefficient for certain types.  You can override this behavior for doubles to make it more efficient via a template specialization

```
template<>
size_t hash_value<double>(const double& key) {
    return // Some awesome double hashing algorithm 
}
```

Putting this definition above your `main` method will cause the calls to `stdext::hash_value(354.566)` to bind to this definition as opposed to the standard one

Comment: A proper pointer to pointer casting will do but Why don't they just provide this very basic functionality?

Comment: @sad_man I really have no idea on why they chose this particular default.

Comment: The problem here isn't the size, it's that the double is being converted to an integer and losing it's decimal portion.

Comment: avoid specialization when simple overload works :) I would also avoid the `double const&`, the indirection is unnecessary for built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

That's old code - doesn't seem very good.

You should probably try std::hash instead.

Comment: `std::hash()` was introduced in TR1.  Does VS2010 support it?

Answer (score 0):

This is, apparently, an attempt to provide a generic hash function for
integers (although I don't see what the xor adds).  It quite clearly
won't work for most other types.  Including floating point.

Providing a good hash function for a floating point value is difficult;
if I were trying to make a generic hash, I'd probably start by testing
for 0, NaN and Inf, and returning predefined hashes for those (or
rejecting NaN completely as it is not a valid hashable value), and then
simply using a standard string hash on the underlying bytes.  This will
at least make hashing compatible with the == operator.  But the problems
of precision mean that == itself may not be what is needed.  Nor <, in
the case of std::map, since std::map uses < to define an equality
relationship, and depending on the source of the floats or doubles, such
an equality relationship might not be appropriate for a hash table.

At any rate, don't expect to find a standard hash function for the floating point types.

Comment: I think that hashing the memory representation of a floating point value would yield a good hash, and I would not even bother to test for specific values.

Comment: Just hashing the memory representation doesn't provide a valid hash for the specific values; that's why I treated them separately.  Remember, an important invariant of the hash function is `a == b` => `hash(a) == hash(b)`.  In the case of 0, +0 and -0 have different representations in memory, although they compare equal.  I'm not sure about Inf, maybe you don't have to treat it specially, and NaN's never compare equal, and so can't be used as a key anyway.

Comment: the std::hash<double> vc10 introduces hashes both zeroes to the same value but otherwise hashes the bits, so it's at least well-behaved over the finite values.  The whole idea of hashing floating point numbers does seem kind of perverse though.

Answer (score 0):

VC10 contains the C++0x Standard hashing mechanisms, so there's no need to use the `stdext` ones anymore, and `std::hash` does contain a mechanism for `double` which performs a bitwise conversion and then hashes. That code that you have for `stdext` is just a fallback mechanism, and it's not really intended for use with floating-point types. I guess it's a design oversight.

```
template<>
class hash<double>
    : public unary_function<double, size_t>
{   // hash functor
public:
typedef double _Kty;
typedef _ULonglong _Inttype;    // use first 2*32 bits

size_t operator()(const _Kty& _Keyval) const
    {   // hash _Keyval to size_t value by pseudorandomizing transform
    _Inttype _Bits = *(_Inttype *)&_Keyval;
    return (hash<_Inttype>()(
        (_Bits & (_ULLONG_MAX >> 1)) == 0 ? 0 : _Bits));
    }
};
```